# SAP Background RFC (bgRFC) destination is not operational

Tags: abap, saprfc, bapi

I've been trying to set bgRFC mode in my **SAPGUI 7.40rev1** but when I verify the configurations with transaction `SRT_ADMIN_CHECK`, I get stuck with the error **`bgRFC destination is not operational`**.

While reviewing SAP's documentation I found that most of the configuration is done using **`client 000`** (for which I don't have access at the moment).

Can someone tell me if this is the error cause? Or there might be some other configuration missing?

Comment: Client 000 is no operational client at all, afaik. It is some kind of SAP-basis administration client, where base-configuration stuff is set up, prior to transport those settings to operational clients. You should ask for setting the stuff up in 000 client, and transport it, or for permissions.

Comment: That appears to be the issue. Thanks for the clarification.